# Gunicorn direct launch in python via egg

Tags: python, flask, gunicorn

I'm using gunicorn w/wsgi (no paster or django) to run flask. Now I am interested to build an egg package for my app and run it directly. When I do this, my app begins to start, but fails to initialize.

Script

```
# note the PYTHONPATH is already set to my .egg, which is confirmed by the output below
python setup.py bdist_egg; python -m gunicorn.app.wsgiapp server.dummy
```

Code: server/dummy.py

```
from flask import *
from util.config import setting
import logging
from logging import FileHandler

app = Flask('server.dummy')
app.debug = True

file_handler = FileHandler("/tmp/flask.log")
file_handler.setLevel(logging.INFO)
app.logger.addHandler(file_handler)

mydumbblueprint = Blueprint('mydumbblueprint', __name__)

@mydumbblueprint.route('/')
def whatever():
    return jsonify({'whatever': 'is right!'})

app.register_blueprint(mydumbblueprint)
app.logger.info('loading: %s' % app.name)
```

And here's the output:

```
2014-11-06 15:37:19 [64098] [INFO] Starting gunicorn 18.0
2014-11-06 15:37:19 [64098] [INFO] Listening at: http://127.0.0.1:8000 (64098)
2014-11-06 15:37:19 [64098] [INFO] Using worker: sync
2014-11-06 15:37:19 [64101] [INFO] Booting worker with pid: 64101
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
INFO in dummy [/Volumes/opt/src/dio/distillerizer/server/dummy.py:20]:
loading: server.dummy
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Failed to find application: 'server.dummy'
2014-11-06 15:37:20 [64101] [INFO] Worker exiting (pid: 64101)
2014-11-06 15:37:20 [64098] [INFO] Shutting down: Master
2014-11-06 15:37:20 [64098] [INFO] Reason: App failed to load.
```

I know that Flask docs use Flask(**name**) to initialize the app, but since my server code is nested in a package that will not work at least as far as I can tell. If maybe there's a way to have the code loaded from package.module X, but referenced by another name between gunicorn & flask?